# Easily writing mocks that hold state

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, googletest, googlemock

I'm testing some code that makes heavy use of callbacks, it looks something like this:

```
class Client {
 public:
  Client(Socket socket) {
    socket->onA([this] {
        // call private Client methods....
      });
    socket->onB([this] {
        // call private Client methods...
      });
    // repeated for onC, onD, and onE
  }

  void Start();
  void Stop();
 private:
  // and almost all of the state is private
};
```

which communicates with the outside world almost entirely by means of the interface provided by `Socket`, which looks like:

```
class Socket {
 public:
  void onA(std::function<void()> callBack) = 0;
  void onB(std::function<void()> callBack) = 0;
  void onC(std::function<void()> callBack) = 0;
  void onD(std::function<void()> callBack) = 0;
  void onE(std::function<void()> callBack) = 0;

  // various other public methods
};
```

It's important that I can both verify that the `onX` functions have been called, and get access to the arguments that were passed to them (because the `Client`'s state changes in response to notifications from the `Socket`, I need to simulate those in my tests).

I can write a mock that looks like:

```
class MockSocket : public Socket {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD1(onA, void(std::function<void()> callBack));
  MOCK_METHOD1(onB, void(std::function<void()> callBack));
  // etc
};
```

but I need to be able to write expectations of the form: "expect that this `MockSocket` object had its `onA` method called once, now call the function that was passed as an argument to `onA`. Now check that the `write` method of `Socket` was called with this string:...."

In another case when I had only one function of this kind, I did something like:

```
class MockSocket : public Socket {
 public:
  // as before

  void setCallbackForA(std::function<void()> callBack) {
    callbackForA = callBack;
  }

  void callCallbackForA() {
    callbackForA();
  }

  // etc

 private:
  std::function<void()> callbackForA;
  std::function<void()> callbackForB;
  // etc
};
```

But that's going to be a ridiculous amount of boilerplate to get this done (5 getters and 5 setters + all of the `EXPECT_CALL`s, which will very slightly from testcase to testcase), and I suspect that there must be a better way to do this (without resorting to C-style macros). Is there some template magic that can help? Anything to make it a little easier to deal with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are testing `Client` class - so what you really need is to store the callback functions that `Client` registers in `Socket`. Do this by `SaveArg<N>` action. See code:

```
class ClientTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    std::function<void()> onACallback;
    std::function<void()> onBCallback;
    //...
    MockSocket mockSocket;
    std::unique_ptr<Client> objectUnderTest;
    void SetUp() override
    {
       using ::testing::SaveArg;
       EXPECT_CALL(mockSocket, onA(_)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&onACallback));
       EXPECT_CALL(mockSocket, onB(_)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&onBCallback));
       //...
       objectUnderTest = std::make_unique<Client>(mockSocket);

    }
};
```

With the Test class above - you can gather all the callbacks. And you can use these catched callbacks to trigger actions in you Client class, like in the test case below:

```
TEST_F(ClientTest, shallDoThisAndThatOnA)
{
   // here you put some expectations
   //...
   onACallback(); // here you trigger your Client object under test
   // now you make some assertions (post actions)
   //...
}
```